# Website menu hover css IE8 issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a site here
http://www.deltacars.co.uk/testsite/

The menu and hover work fine in all browsers including IE8 but when I go to the another page which is using the same html and css the menu does not appear correct

http://www.deltacars.co.uk/testsite/north-wales-private-hire/privatehire.html

Please note that this is only using IE 8.

Anyone know why it works fine on one page and not the other

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please recreate this on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something similar. It's not useful posting actual links because the problem will only exist in a small period of time and will not be useful to others in the future. Also many members don't like clicking unknown links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The broken page is missing some conditional IE comments in the header. All you need to do is right click and view the page source to compare the output.

```
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="shiv/dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Why are you repeating the condition twice? Why not place both script lines in the first condition?

Answer (score 0):

Give your website a thorough validation using http://validator.w3.org - my guess is that one of your 241 errors is causing this not to render correctly in IE8.

"Modern" browsers are intelligent enough to render elements correctly despite the mark-up being incorrect, hence why you're not seeing the problem on any others.

Comment: all those errors seem to come from the modernizer code I am using